# event.preventDefault() doesn't avoid opening the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hyperlink

I have the following piece of code but despite using event.preventDefault() clicking the link still results in opening that target div! I have read all the questions regarding this issue in stackoverflow, but neither of them solved my problem. The alert part is done but event.preventDefault() does not work! Please help me!

the html is:

```
<ul class="projects-info">
   <li><a href="#tabs-1">file upload</a></li>                                                                       
   <li class="projects-det"><a href="#tabs-2">file specification</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="border:1px solid  #1c94c4;" id="tabs-2">
   this is the div content
</div>
```

the jQuery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function ()
   {
      $("ul.projects-info li.projects-det a").bind('click',function(event)
      {
         event = event || window.event;
     alert("for checking");
         if(event.preventDefault)
         {
            event.preventDefault(); 
         }
         if (event.stopPropagation) 
         {
            event.stopPropagation();
         }
         return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net? Note that jQuery normalizes the `preventDefault` method and there is no need check the method and the `preventDefault` doesn't stop other handlers from being executed.

Comment: Your code as shown works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/Thrfn/ - do you have other JS/jQuery on the page? Further to what undefined said about jQuery normalising `preventDefault()` it also normalises the `event` object so there's no need for the test with `window.event`. Same for `stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using some other library to support a tabbed interface.

If the link is a regular hyperlink to another page, then yes `preventDefault` would stop that happening.

However if there are two handlers bound to the same event (in your case 'click') then each work independently of each other.  You can't control the order, and they can't suppress each other.

So the handlers that are bound to perform the tabbing still get activated.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4J9Ap/

Two handlers are bound to the same link - both fire.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
   {
      $("ul.projects-info li.projects-det a").bind('click',function(event)
      {
         event = event || window.event;
         if(event.preventDefault)
         {
            event.preventDefault(); 
         }
         if (event.stopPropagation) 
         {
            event.stopPropagation();
         }
         alert("handler 1")
         return false;
      });

     $("a#myLink").bind('click',function(event)
      {
         event = event || window.event;
         if(event.preventDefault)
         {
            event.preventDefault(); 
         }
         if (event.stopPropagation) 
         {
            event.stopPropagation();
         }
          alert("handler 2")
         return false;
      });
});
```

Comment: Rob Shepherd You are too smart:) Yeah that is right. I have two tabs (links), that clicking each one results in showing the correspondent div(contents).

Comment: But I want to disable the second tab. I mean I need the user to first complete the information in the first div (first tab). If not he should not be able to visit second tab (div) contents. This is why I used preventDefault() on second tab, but it seems it does not work. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: You could work out how the tabbing is enabled in the first place and then only add tab-2 when you are ready. Also you can destroy *ALL* handlers using `off()` (see http://jsfiddle.net/4J9Ap/1/ ) and then try and put them back later. not easy eh?! :) Unfortunately it's hard to do when you have other frameworks/libraries weaving their magic to your page elements.